# Non linear Interpolation with the Forecast function

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to do a nonlinear interpolation of a particular number in a column and get the equivalent number in the second column. It gives me a compiler error with list separator or )

```
 Sub interp()
 Dim temp As Integer
 Dim var As Integer
 Dim var1 As Integer
 Dim xs As Range
 Dim ys As Range
 Set xs = Sheets(1).Range("A8:A19")
 Set ys = Sheets(1).Range("B8:B19")
 temp = Sheets(1).Range("E3").Value
 Dim indexxs As Integer
 Dim indexys As Integer
 Dim indexxs1 As Integer
 Dim indexys1 As Integer


 var = WorksheetFunction.Match(temp, xs, 1)
 var1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(temp, xs, 1) + 1


 indexxs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xs, var)
 indexxs1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(xs, var1)
 indexys = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ys, var)
 indexys1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ys, var1)




 Sheets(1).Range("g3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(temp,indexys:indexys1,indexxs:indexxs1)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forcast wants a range or an array and not numbers which is what you are passing with `indexys:indexys1`  You are passing the values of the index, so it would return something like `104:34` and not a range or an array.

You could change the Forcast line to:

```
Sheets(1).Range("g3").value = Application.Forecast(temp, Array(indexys, indexys1), Array(indexxs, indexxs1))
```

and it will work, but there are better, quicker methods to get the outcome desired using vba and not worksheet functions.

So we can get rid of the index and create an array of the values.  Then use those arrays in the formula.

```
 Sub interp()
 Dim temp As Long
 Dim var As Long
 Dim var1 As Long
 Dim xs As Range
 Dim ys As Range

 With Worksheets(1)
     Set xs = .Range("A8:A19")
     Set ys = .Range("B8:B19")
     temp = .Range("E3").value


    var = WorksheetFunction.Match(temp, xs, 1)
    var1 = var + 1


     Dim y As Variant
     y = .Range(ys.Cells(var, 1), ys.Cells(var1, 1)).value
     Dim x As Variant
     x = .Range(xs.Cells(var, 1), xs.Cells(var1, 1)).value


    .Range("g3").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(temp, y, x)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: @dejioni please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: is it possible to do this for an entire row